# Using variables through other procedures in C

Tags: c, function, procedure

I've this:

```
    void
    insideword(char *str, int wordstart, int contador, char **args, int word, int inword, int lenstr) {
        if (detectpattern(str[contador])) {
            inword = 0;
            str[contador] = '\0';
            args[word] = &str[wordstart];
        }
        if (contador == lenstr-2) {
            args[word] = &str[wordstart];   
        }   
    }

    int
    mytokenize(char *str, char **args, int maxargs) {
        int contador;
        int inword;
        int wordstart;
        int word;
        int lenstr;

        contador = 0;
        wordstart = 0;
        inword = 1;
        word = 0;
        lenstr = (strlen(str)-1);

        while (str[contador] != '\0')
        {
            if (inword == 1) {
                insideword(str, wordstart, contador, args, word, inword, lenstr);
                printf("%i", inword);
            } 
            contador++;
        }
    }
```

well... my program doesn't work fine. If I printf "inword" just before insideword, inword is ALWAYS 1, and never is been modified by insideword proc.

If I print it inside insideword proc, just before inword = 0, but it doesn't return the value 0.

Thanks

Comment: I've done it, this is why I don't know why doesn't work

Comment: Oh, I misread you, sorry. You should post the code as you describe it in the question (with comments if you wish to highlight "conditional" lines)

Comment: You have done "it"? what is "it"?

Comment: does `detectpattern` expect/operate on a string or on a single character (as it is now, given `str[contador]` is a single character)?

Comment: What do you expect `void f(int i) {i = 5;} int main() {int x=7; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` to print?

Answer (score 3):

Right now, you pass `inword` (from `mytokenize`) by value, ie, the parameter `inword` of `insideword` has it's own memory and gets a copy of `inword` from `mytokenize` (its two distinct variables, just having the same name -- but both are not related to each other). If you modify `inword` of `insideword` you only modify the copy but not the original variable.

If you want `inword` parameter (for `insideword`) to be "the same variable" as `inword` from `mytokenizer`, you need to "pass by reference" using a pointer:

> Change `int inword` to `int *inword` in parameter list of `insideword`.

Additionally you need to change the call to `insideword` in `mytokenize` to:

> insideword(str, wordstart, contador, args, word, &inword, lenstr);

Because `inword` is a variable but the function uses a pointer as parameter you need to pass the address of `inword` using `&`.

If you pass by reference, the parameter does not get a copy but "points" to the same memory as `inword` from `mytokenizer` and your write will be visible to `inword` of `mytokenizer`. However, you need to dereference the pointer before you can write to it:

> Change `inword = 0` to `*inword = 0` in `insideword`

If you do not de-ref via `*` your code will still compile. But the write is not done to the variable the pointer is pointing to, but changes the pointer's address resulting in a dangling pointer which is dangerous and might result in undefined behavior!

Comment: Except, C doesn't have C++-style references. This problem requires pass-by-reference using a _pointer_.